# Xcode8 Tencent TIM -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "timapiV1://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

Tags: ios

In The use of Tencent QQ SDK 3.2.0 (iOS version) do TIM share tips "- canOpenURL: failed for URL:"timapiV1://"- The error:" The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error - 10814.). "

I have been added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes value:"timopensdkapiV4", "timapiV1", "timapi" and "tim". I have been installed the TIM App on mine iPhone.

Could you tell me what should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is TIM App's Bug. TIM Team had resolved it.